# Usage of Memory in Java bean and session variables

Tags: tomcat7, javabeans, session-variables, session-management

I am using tomcat Apache server for my web app. I need to know if using bean would reduce my memory usage than the session variables i use ? Also what is the limit of storing session variables in bytes and that of a bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are storing the objects of the bean.
if they are being stored in session. its same.